# Сделать ветвление в xslt

Tags: xslt

есть код который принимает значение пола пользователя.

```
<m0:sex><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='sex']"/></m0:sex>
```

сам код

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Импорт базового шаблона -->
  <xsl:import href="airBaseTemplate.xsl"/>
  <xsl:param name="serviceCode">333</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="requestName">PublicWorksRequest</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="caseNumber"><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='caseNumber']"/></xsl:param>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- Шаблон данных заявления -->
  <xsl:template name="processAppData">
    <//настройки и пр>
               <m0:person>
                  <m0:lastName><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='lastName']"/></m0:lastName>
                  //ряд других полей
     <xsl:variable name="snils"><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='SNILS']"/></xsl:variable>
                <m0:SNILS><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($snils,1,3),'-',substring($snils,4,3),'-', substring($snils,7,3), ' ', substring($snils,9,2))"/></m0:SNILS>
                <m0:UdDoc>
                  <m0:VidDoc><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='VidDoc']"/></m0:VidDoc>
                  <m0:NumDoc><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='NumDoc']"/></m0:NumDoc>
                  <m0:IssDoc><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='IssDoc']"/></m0:IssDoc>
                  <m0:DatDoc><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='DatDoc']"/></m0:DatDoc>
                </m0:UdDoc>
                <m0:sex><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='sex']"/>
</m0:sex>


               <m0:telephone><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='telephone' and local-name(parent::*)='smvTelephoneTableWebClass']"/></m0:telephone>
        <m0:email><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='email' and local-name(parent::*)='smvEmailTableWebClass']"/></m0:email>
             <xsl:call-template name="addressTemplate">
                          <xsl:with-param name="addressField" select="//*[local-name()='__address']"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                <m0:timeVisiting>
                  <m0:startDate><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='gstartDate']"/></m0:startDate>
                  <m0:timeFrom><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='timeFrom']"/></m0:timeFrom>
                  <m0:timeTo><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='timeTo']"/></m0:timeTo>
                </m0:timeVisiting>
                <m0:abonent><xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='abonent']"/></m0:abonent>
        </smev:PublicWorksType>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

сейчас выводиться либо male либо female. мне нужно заменить вывод цифрами, male -1, female -2

как организовать такую логику?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В xslt есть два способа: `if` и `choose`.

Будет что-то вроде:

```
<xsl:template match="sex">
  <sex>
    <xsl:if test=". = 'male'">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=". = 'female'">
      <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </sex>
</xsl:template>
```

или

```
<xsl:template match="sex">
  <sex>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = 'male'">
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </sex>
</xsl:template>
```

Условий `when` может быть сколько угодно.

В данном случае больше подходит `choose`. Потому каждый оператор `if` будет делать проверку, в то время как в `choose` после первого совпадения остальные ветки пропускаются.

---

Чтобы применить этот шаблон, замените в вашем коде строку

```
<xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='sex']"/>
```

на строку

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="sex"/>
```

Возможно, придется в `select` писать `//*[local-name()='sex']`. Но правильнее использовать указание пространства имен. Для этого нужно видеть входной xml.

Comment: спасибо. подскажите в строке <xsl:if test=". = 'male'"> что означает точка ".

Comment: @Padawan - значение текущего узла. Узел задан в `match`. Я мог бы привести более полный пример, если бы видел больше вашего кода и входной xml.

Comment: привел основную часть кода.

Comment: @Padawan - обновил ответ.